# problem installing mongodb on fedora

Tags: fedora, mongodb

I'm trying to install `mongodb` on `fedora 22` and this is the error i get

```
$ yum search mongo-org

Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'MongoDB' from 'http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/22/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried, disabling.
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:13:12 ago on Tue Jun  9 16:01:19 2015.
Error: No matches found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create:

```
sudo gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
```

with the following content: (for 64-bit)

```
[mongodb]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

then install

```
sudo yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server
```

running mongo:

```
service mongod start
```

see for more information:
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

Answer (score 5):

This url simply does not exist (anymore?).

They only furnish red hat RPMs now : http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/

I guess the closest Red hat version to Fedora 22 is RHEL7...

Comment: thanks for the help - i googled RHEL 7 mongodb and it was easy enough from there. +1